# Native element null at Angular test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

I was trying to emulate a click inside my component for unit testing following Angular Documentation but for some reason my native element is returning empty: `HTMLButtonElement {}`

At first I had to add the detectChanges function because of my ngIf but later on no changes were reflecting.

Here's also my HTML:

```
<div class="money-transfer-options" *ngIf="card">
    <div class="alert alert__info" role="alert">
        <i class="nc nc-icon-alert-circle-i"></i> Haremos un cargo con la cantidad seleccionada a la tarjeta con
        terminación:
        {{ card.card_number | bankAccountLastFourDigits }}
    </div>

    <form class="money-transfer-options__form" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <label
            [for]="'moneyTransferAmount' + i"
            class="money-transfer-options__card"
            *ngFor="let amount of amounts; index as i"
            (click)="toggleActiveClass(i)"
        >
            <input
                type="radio"
                class="money-transfer-options__card-radio"
                [id]="'moneyTransferAmount' + i"
                [value]="amount"
                formControlName="amountTransfer"
                required
            />
            <span class="money-transfer-options__card-amount">
                <span class="money-transfer-options__card-icon"></span>
                <span class="money-transfer-options__card-currency-symbol">$</span>
                <span class="money-transfer-options__card-total">{{ amount | currency: 'MXN':'':'1.0-0' }}</span>
                <span class="money-transfer-options__card-comission">
                    Comisión: <br />
                    <span class="money-transfer-options__card-comission-amount">
                        {{ amount * commission + fee | currency: 'MXN':'symbol':'1.2-2' }}
                    </span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </label>
        <button
            type="submit"
            class="button button__primary money-transfer-options__submit"
            aria-label="Agregar fondos a mi cuenta"
            [disabled]="!form.valid"
        >
            Agregar Fondos
        </button>
    </form>

    <small class="money-transfer-options__disclaimer">
        *Las transacciones tardan en promedio hasta 5 minutos en verse reflejadas.
    </small>
</div>
```

Here's my spec.ts file:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    const configure: ConfigureFn = testBed => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
            declarations: [MoneyTransferOptionsComponent, BankAccountLastFourPipe],
            providers: []
        }).compileComponents();
    };

    configureTests(configure).then(testBed => {
        fixture = testBed.createComponent(MoneyTransferOptionsComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        component.card = expectedTokenizedCard;
        component.amounts = expectedAmounts;

        fixture.detectChanges();
    });
}));

it('should emit the payload for the request', async () => {
    component.card = expectedTokenizedCard;

    fixture.detectChanges();

    await fixture.whenStable();

    const submitButton = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.money-transfer-options__submit'));
    let submitButtonEl = submitButton.nativeElement;

    let testPayload: Common.TokenizedCardDeposit;

    console.log(submitButtonEl);


    //component.onFormSubmit.subscribe((payload: Common.TokenizedCardDeposit) => (testPayload = payload));

    //submitButtonEl.triggerEventHandler('click', null);
    // expect(testPayload).toBe(expectedPayload);
});
```

Comment: could you provide your html please?

Comment: There you go @JSmith

Comment: Try using `.queryAll()` and assigning submitButtonEl with `submitButton[0]`?

Comment: Not working either @terahertz

Comment: maybe silly but how come `fixture` is inside two functions without beign global?

Comment: You can try something like, spy on the method then

const button = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('button');
button.click();

fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
   expect(component.onEditButtonClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
}); @Alex

Comment: I can't spy and empty object which is currently retrieving the nativeElement. @ramana

Comment: Stil not working @JSmith

Comment: @Alex could you make a stackblitz or is it unsupported for unit testing?

Comment: Could not create unit testing with my configuration @JSmith, sorry.